Dual screens are not working in Ubuntu 24.04
I have update Ubuntu to Ubuntu 24.04 and the system does not detect my second screen:

Settings -> Displays
My  graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M
Additional Drivers:

Results of ubuntu-drivers devices :
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000139Asv0000103Csd00008421bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-545 - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

Results of lspci | egrep "VGA|3D" :
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)


You have upgraded from who knows what to Ubuntu Core 24? You need to add some more details and if it is not Ubuntu Core the correct version info, please. The title says 24.04 but the question just says 24.

I upgraded from Ubuntu 23.10 to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS when my system displayed the version change notification
